# Passing Credentials ID To Jenkins Job via URL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline style setup where credentials are passed into the job through a parameter. The credentials are an AWS IAM role.

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    parameters {
        // AWS Credential for creating the AMIs
        credentials(
            credentialType: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AWSCredentialsImpl',
            defaultValue: '',
            description: 'AWS Credentials for AMI Generation',
            name: 'aws_credentials',
            required: true)
    }
   ...
```

The stage that uses the credentials does so thusly:

```
            stage('Build AMI') {
                steps {
                    withCredentials([
                        aws(credentialsId: "aws_credentials"),
                    sh '''
                        #!/bin/bash
                        ...
```

This works when running the job through the UI, you can either select a global set of credentials if available, or else select a personal set of credentials.

However, when running the job via a python script using an API token, etc. and passing in the ID of the credentials the job will run, but fail (with no error message) while trying to start the `Build AMI` stage.
The python script is using the [python-jenkins](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. The user definitely has access to the global credentials I'm testing with.

```py
queue_number = server.build_job(JOB['NAME'],
                                parameters={"aws_credentials": AWS_CREDENTIALS_ID},
                                token=JOB['TOKEN'])
```

I need to understand how to pass in the credentials ID correctly in order for the job to work successfully. I guess because the parameter is a class type, passing in a simple string for the ID does not appear to be enough, even though when I inspect the scripted job's parameters a link is shown to the correct credentials for the ID!?